# Android ADB commands missing

Tags: android

I've got Android 2.2 on my phone and I'm doing some DB development. I've been trying to query my DB using sqlite3, but it looks like sqlite3 is missing from my phone. So then I tried a few other commands (su, find etc) and they ALL seem to be missing.

Can anyone tell me where they have gone please? I read somewhere that sqlite3 at least might have been accidentally left out of 2.2, but surely they can't all have been missed off can they?

Thanks

Comment: Consumers generally don't need `su` and `sqlite3` etc, as there is no need, i.e. you can't access `/data/data` as a regular user. Emulators, Android Developer Phones and Custom ROMs generally *do* include these binaries.

Answer (score 0):

With the new release, adb has moved to `platform-tools` while all other tools are still under `tools` folder.

You can either copy them or add them to the Windows `Path` (if you are using windows).

Comment: Thanks Aliostad, I've found sqlite3.exe now. But, the google docs suggest connecting to my phone using "adb -d shell" and then issuing sqlite3 commands to connect to my app's db. I copied sqlite3.exe to the platform-tools folder, and also added it to my path, but when I go into an ADB shell, I get "sqlite3: not found". As an aside, is the reason I can't 'su' and 'find' because my phone isn't rooted? Bit new to this as you can tell...

Comment: Mine works with no copying or setting path. I am surprised. But yes su is the reason that phone is not rooted. Can you sqlite3 for emulator?

Comment: I can sqlite3 to a db on my local filesystem, but I'd like to access the one on my phone. These are the commands I want to issue (taken from the docs): $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db

Comment: I see. A few things don't quite make sense here: 1) adb -s emulator-5554 will shell to an emulator 2) it is possible that /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db does not exist so the error you get is actually not found by SQlite3 and not adb. do this -> adb shell -> sqlite3 see if works

Comment: depends on the phone the emulator has sqlite3 yes but most phones don't.  Although most mods do have it, I suggest cyanogenmod if you have a supported phone.

Comment: The example I gave above was taken straight from the docs; it's referring to an emulator, not my phone, but that's the kind of thing I want to achieve. adb shell -> sqlite3 gives me 'sqlite3: not found'; I think this is the sqlite3 client itself that cant be found, not my db. Will try cyanogenmod I can see it on Market, will that give me all the developer tools/commands my phone is missing (it's a Galaxy S btw in case that helps)

Comment: Ah, it works fine on the emulator. Right, so basically I need to root my phone to get all this goodness (root access, sqlite3 etc) because Samsung have only given me a little bit. OK, here goes (my warranty)...

Comment: Rooting your phone won't void your warranty (they might technically say it does, but in all practical purposes it won't.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ adb -s <serialno> shell type sqlite3
sqlite3 is /system/xbin/sqlite3
```

to determine if `sqlite3` is available or not on you device.

The command you entered in one of your comments is malformed, it should be (after you determined that `sqlite3` is available):

```
$ adb -s <serialno> shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't adb commands those are binaries usually installed on rooted devices.  If your device isn't rooted you aren't going to be able to install them either.

However, what you can do to get into your apps database.  Use the activity manager command `set-debug-app [options] <PACKAGE>` This will let you access your apps database without being rooted, then you can pull it to your desktop and use sqlite3 from there.

Something like this:

```
adb shell
am set-debug-app com.example.appname
exit ##exit adb shell
adb pull data/data/com.example.appname/databases/exampledb.db exampledb.db
sqlite3 exampledb.db
```

Your app needs to be set to debugging true in the manifest for this to work.